# Problems with Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WinFormErrorExample 
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Form1 Instance;
        public Form1()
        {
            Instance = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ChangeLabel1Text(String msg)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(new Action<String>(m => label1.Text = m), new object[] {msg});
            else
                label1.Text = msg;
        } 

        static class Program
        {
            [STAThread]
            static void Main()
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
                Instance.ChangeLabel1Text("cool");
            }
        }
   }
}
```

When i'm calling the `Instance.ChangeLabel1Text("cool");` nothing is happening in the GUI.

This is a small program i constructed to show my problem in a larger program.

Why is the GUI not being updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application.Run(new Form1());` method call performs running a standard application message loop on the current thread. So, this line `Instance.ChangeLabel1Text("cool");` will be executed when the application is closed.

Why not change the text of the label inside the constructor? No static variables needed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChangeLabel1Text("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

is blocking your application until the Form1 closes. So your subsequent line is not executed until you try to close

Of course, if you just want to test the functionality of the Instance call then remove that line after the Application.Run. Instead you need to create a separate thread that tries to call that method on the Form1 current instance

Comment: @Jacob You can call this ChangeLabel1Text() in Form_Load() function and it will work as expected!

Answer (score 0):

This would do,

First set the text to textbox control and then `Run()`

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.Controls["ChangeLabel1Text"].Text = "cool";
Application.Run(form);
```